# Detect wrong UTF8 character on string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading a csv file in `node.js` that contains urls, I want to be able to detect when a string contains this character � or any other character that is not the proper UTF8 symbol.

Wrong URL I want to be able to detect:

```js
'https://example.com/v�hicules-de-location/france'
```

Right URL I want to ignore

```js
'https://example.com/véhicules-de-location/france'
```

Is there an easy way with JavaScript to do that?

Comment: Usually, when you get that character, you're reading the file using a wrong encoding. There is not a proper way to understand what the single character originally was. Instead, you should use the correct encoding when reading the file, and everything else will work fine as it is.

Comment: I know, but that's not my question, I know they uploaded the wrong encoded file, that's why I want to be able to detect it

Comment: I do not control the file, the symbol already comes like that written on the csv so there is no encodign mechanism that is going to turn a `�` into a `é`

Comment: The question is how you read the file. Can you post that code as well?

Comment: No, the question is how to detect a wrong UTF8 character

Comment: @gaitat it does not really matter how I read it if the file contains � anyway before I even read it right?

Comment: Yes you fixed the issue by introducing (in my opinion, ugly code). In addition you dont know if tomorrow a different undesirable character will appear in your input file.

Comment: Try `Readable.setEncoding('utf8')`

Comment: @gaitat but again what good is that going to do if the file already comes with �?

Comment: Prefer the solution of @MaReAL below

Answer (score -2):

The file comes with the � already in there, I can see it when I open it with a text editor, it's already there once the � is there, there is nothing it can be done to encode it properly.

In the end I am doing this, cause the 'corrupted' character comes like that already and is not something I can control.

```
....

import csv from 'csv-parser'
import { Readable } from 'stream'

export default async (buffer) => {
  const json = []

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Readable.from(buffer)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (data) => {
        const corrupted = Object.values(data).some((entry) => /�/.test(entry))

        if (corrupted) reject('encoding')

        json.push(data) 
      })
      .on('end', async () => {
        resolve(writeFile ....)
      })
  })
}
```